# File won't transfer from temp file back to original

Tags: java, file

Here is an extract of my code.
I have searched around Stack Overflow and have done all of the suggestions i.e. delete original and rename temp to original, I have tried writer.flush as well. Here is what the .txt files look like.

GradeEnter:

```
1) Bob Do, Comp, 18
2) Matt Well, computing, 100
3) Adam Smith, Computing, 99
4) Mike Frank-Jones, Drama, 69
```

MyTempFile:

```
Matt Well, computing, 100
Adam Smith, Computing, 99
Mike Frank-Jones, Drama, 69
```

Grade Enter (After Deletion):

```
Bob Do, Comp, 18
Matt Well, computing, 100
Adam Smith, Computing, 99
Mike Frank-Jones, Drama, 69
```

Why is this? Thanks

```
    File deleteRecord = new File("GradeEnter.txt");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(deleteRecord));

    File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("To delete, please Enter First Name: ");
    firstNameDelete = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Surname: ");
    lastNameDelete = scanner.nextLine();

    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(currentLine.contains(firstNameDelete) && currentLine.contains(lastNameDelete)) continue;
        writer.write(currentLine);
        writer.newLine();
    }
    reader.close(); 
    writer.close();
    deleteRecord.delete();
    tempFile.renameTo(deleteRecord);
```

Comment: How can you see the temp file, since it's supposed to be deleted? Conclusion: the rename doesn't happen. Don't ignore the boolean returned from delete() and renameTo().

Comment: How come File.delete() doesn't throw an exception when delete fails?

Comment: @JBNizet I had the temp file open at the time. When trying with it closed, still nothing happens

Comment: @Adam do `Boolean deletedSuccessfully=deleteRecord.delete();` and print the value of `deletedSuccessfullly` It should be true for your code to work. same with `renamedSuccessfully=tempFile.renameTo(deleteRecord);`

Comment: You can also stick those two lines in a try block and see if you can catch an exception that will tell you what exactly is going wrong. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html).

Comment: @RaGe It doesn't throw an exception because it returns a boolean instead.

Comment: @EJP to me that just seems contrary to how run-time errors are handled elsewhere in Java. Returning errors in return values is a very C thing to do.

Comment: @RaGe I think we all agree. But just because we think it should throw an exception won't make the methods do that.

Comment: @RaGe both are false!

Comment: Well now you know delete fails, which is why your code fails. Did you try the try-catch block. I would try a `Thread.sleep(100);` after your close statements.

Comment: Thread.sleep(100) did not work. What try / catch (es) should I use?

Comment: There is a link in one of my comments, about 7 comments up.